Show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n (k + s)} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{s^n} H_s + \frac{(-1)^n}{s^{n+1}} \sum_{k=2}^n (-s)^k \zeta(k)$
Claim
For positive integers $n$ and $s$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n (k + s)} =  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{s^n} H_s + \frac{(-1)^n}{s^{n+1}} \sum_{k=2}^n (-s)^k \zeta(k)
$$
where

$H_s = \sum_{k=1}^s \frac{1}{k}$ is the $s$-th harmonic number.
$\zeta(k) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Example
It simplifies these types of problems: Show that $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$
Let $s=1, n=2$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2 (k+1)} 
&= \frac{(-1)^{2+1}}{1^2} H_1 + \frac{(-1)^2}{1^{2+1}} \sum_{k=2}^2 (-1)^k \zeta(k) \nonumber \\
&= \frac{-1}{1^2} H_1 + \frac{1}{1^3} (-1)^2 \zeta(2) \nonumber \\
&= -H_1 + \frac{\zeta(2)}{1} \nonumber \\
&= \zeta(2) - 1 \nonumber \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1.
\end{align}
Is there a proof or reference to that claim?

Let $$T(n,s) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {k^n (k+s)}$$
Note that $$\frac 1 {k^n(k+s)} = \frac 1 s \left (\frac {1} {k^n} - \frac 1 {k^{n-1}(k+s)}\right)$$
Thus
$$T(n,s) = \frac 1 s \zeta(n) - \frac 1 sT(n-1, s)$$
Applying this recursively should yield the result.
